# How to create an empty byte array in perl

Tags: c#, perl

I am trying to port over some code in c# to perl. I am unable to port this piece of code in c#

```
byte[] iv = new byte[16];
```

to Perl.

I tried using pack command in this format but that did not help -

```
my $iv = pack 'x16',"";
```

Any pointers on what to use in perl to create an empty byte array?

Comment: The real question is what are you using it for?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
my $iv = "\0" x 16;
```